# symfony server:start always taking prod configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I have a weird issue with Symfony, in my local environment when I run `symfony server:start` it's taking production configuration not dev configuration.

I have two index files in the public folder `index.php` and `index_dev.php`. I also added a `.env.local` with `APP_ENV=dev`

Also, I tried to set environment variables as the following.

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=dev
```

But `index.php` is always loaded, and not `index_dev.php` as I expected.

How I can fix this?

Comment: And which file do you access? Usually everything is inside `index.php`, because Symfony is not responsible for your index file configuration. E.g. `http://localhost/` goes directly to `index.php` by default and only `http://localhost/index_dev.php` would go to `index_dev.php`

Comment: @Justinas -  I thought it takes based on the ENV

Comment: No, server does not work that way. Unless you have specialized code for that, but I doubt that. Always read documentation before making assumptions

Comment: Older version of Symfony have a web server bundle activated with 'bin/console server:start'. Might give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are copying the `app_dev.php` pattern, which is how it used to be in olden times (up to Symfony 3).

Fortunately, that's no longer how things are done. Since Symfony 4, you should have a single front-controller.

All requests should go through the same entry script (`index.php`, generally), and there you can implement whatever logic you need taking into account the different environments.

The [default `index.php` file](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.3/public/index.php) already has some logic to account for the `APP_DEBUG` environment variable being set, you could always modify this file to add other behaviour depending on the environment.

Comment: I can see `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` in index.php how I can set it to dev

Comment: Check how it's done in the `index.php` that I linked. E.g.: `$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);`. You are probably better off replacing your whole front-controller if you are upgrading to Sf 4.